# How can I identify if a string should take an argument

Tags: python

I am not sure if there is a pretty way of doing this but here is my problem:

I have a dict that reference to some SQL statements:

```
{
  'var1': """select * from sometable where x=%s"""
  'var2': """select * from sometable"""
}
```

I have a script which will either use var1 or var2... but obviously when attempting to pass an argument to `var2` it will throw an exception...

I was wondering if there is a way to identify if a string needs an argument and only then try to pass it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be to count the `%s` strings.

Could fail in some extreme cases, but basically

```
sql_string.count('%s')
```

provides you with the number of expected arguments.

```
d = {
  'var1': """select * from sometable where x=%s""",
  'var2': """select * from sometable"""
}

for k,v in d.items():
    print("{}, {} args".format(k,v.count("%s")))
```

result:

```
var2, 0 args
var1, 1 args
```

had you other formats than `%s` you could use a regular expression to match other formats, like this:

```
len(re.findall("%[ds]",sql_string)
```

Both solutions above are far from perfect. They don't handle `%` escaping for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean?

```
if "%s" in sql_stmt:
    do_something()
```

Also you can use `sql_stmt.count('%s')` to get the number of arguments.

Comment: the .count('%s') will do the trick for me, thanks a lot for the ideas!

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {
  "var1": "select * from sometable where x=%s",
  "var2": "select * from sometable"
}
for k,v in dict.iteritems():
    if "%s" in v:
        print "[%s] needs an argument"%v
    else:
        print "[%s] doesn't need an argument"%v
```

gives :

```
[select * from sometable where x=%s] needs an argument
[select * from sometable] doesn't need an argument
```